# What is a better practice for protecting my app against malicious sign ups - Captcha or confirming user email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I am using Authlogic for a Ruby on Rails (2.3.9) app that I built where users can track workouts. As it grows in popularity I am worried about false/malicious sign-ups. What is the best practice here or advantages and disadvantages to each approach.

Should I simply require that the user confirm their email before successfully accessing my app? Should I only require the user fill out a successful Captcha? Are these two things mutually exclusive or should they be used together?

Just looking for some general discussion around this so I better understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any botnet can set up their own mail server to spam you...

Several can get past captchas too...

Use email confirmation, captchas, and gotchas (Hidden field humans wouldn't fill in)

There are bound to be many others (Bocking all russian and chinese IPs is one of the more extreme ones) but those are the most used currently...

Answer (score 1):

It's been my experience that some spam bots are actually not bots at all but rather humans from 3-world countries paid to sit there and fill out all kinds forms for whatever reason. This means that while email confirmation and captchas help, you're still bound to get some spam.

There's a few other things you could consider:

1. If the site is social, implement a flagging system which causes the community to become the moderator.
2. Have all users disabled by default, then require an admin to approve or delete them.
3. Require a credit card to sign up.

Some of these may or may not work depending on your case. I've found that #3 pretty much eliminates spam all together, but it may also discourage real potential customers.

Comment: +1. The hired help type in the captcha text, which gets mapped to the graphic displayed. Then it's a trivial lookup: find the image that is the same as the one presented on the page, look up the appropriate text in the database, shove it down the httpd server's form-input, and spam away. The fix is to randomly generate the graphic's text or have enough variation in the images that they'll never match a previous image.

Answer (score 0):

Good security has more than one layer.  I would at least use both and also add in functionality for auto-blocking and auto-admin alerts when attempts to escalate privileges/access blocked pages occurs. Write code to make it easy for you to permanently block certain IPs, etc… if you want as well (I like to be able to block from a secure link, because then it can be called by other services with a secure API call).

You should obfuscate email as well anywhere that it appears on a page (in my opinion, as this will help a little; not as much as it used to, though):

```
def obfuscate_email(email)
return nil if email.nil? #Don't bother if the parameter is nil.
lower = ('a'..'z').to_a
upper = ('A'..'Z').to_a
email.split('').map { |char|
    output = lower.index(char) + 97 if lower.include?(char)
    output = upper.index(char) + 65 if upper.include?(char)
    output ? "&##{output};" : (char == '@' ? '&#0064;' : char)
}.join
end
```